# Count organizer_id's if event_paid_type = 'paid event' disregard/don't count if event_paid_type = 'free event'

Tags: sql

I have an organizer_id column, each organizer could hold many events and each event is either 'free event' or 'paid event' in an event_paid_type column.

Data set sample:

```
organizer_id      event_paid_type
9092720            free event
14360170           paid event
16167660           paid event
9092720            paid event
14360170           paid event
16167660           paid event
```

How do I answer this:

**How many organizers have a least one paid order but never a free order?**

I understand how to count up the paid events per organizer_id (which isn't honestly needed) but I don't know how to disregard an organizer_id if event_paid_type = 'free event'

My baby step attempt:

```
SELECT organizer_id, event_paid_type, COUNT(*) as paid_event_count
FROM event_table
WHERE (event_paid_type = 'paid event')
GROUP BY organizer_id, event_paid_type
ORDER BY paid_event_count DESC;
```

current results:

```
organizer_id     event_paid_type     paid_event_count
9092720            paid event               1
14360170           paid event               2
16167660           paid event               2
```

Comment: i removed multiple dbms tags. tag only one dbms you are actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question directly translates to using `not exists`.

```
select count(distinct organizer_id)
from event_table e1
where event_paid_type='paid event' 
and not exists (select 1 
                from event_table e2
                where e1.organizer_id=e2.organizer_id 
                and e2.event_paid_type='free event')
```

Another way to do it is using conditional aggregation.

```
select count(*) 
from event_table
group by organizer_id
having count(case when event_paid_type='free event' then 1 end) = 0
and count(case when event_paid_type='paid event' then 1 end) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks so much vkp, both examples work.

Can you explain or point to where I can read more about this one part?

    and not exists (select 1 
    from event_table e2
    where e1.organizer_id=e2.organizer_id 
    and e2.event_paid_type='free event')

Thanks!